# Can't permanently set `bash` engine path with `knitr::opts_chunk$set(engine.path = ...)`

Tags: r, bash, r-markdown, knitr

#### Background

I have an analysis script in Rmd. I'm using both R and Bash chunks. I want to use my self-installed Bash version (5) instead of the system default version (3).

#### Methods

I've tried setting the path to my preferred Bash engine in 2 ways:

1. by setting it with `knitr::opts_chunk$set(engine.path = list(bash = '/usr/local/bin/bash'))`
2. by setting it on a per-chunk basis with the chunk header like:

````
```{bash, engine.path='/usr/local/bin/bash'}
````

#### Results

The 2nd approach appears to work while the first does not. Here is a minimal reprex:

````
​```{r setup}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(engine.path = list(bash = '/usr/local/bin/bash'))
​```

​```{bash test, engine.opts='-l'}
echo "$BASH_VERSION"
​```
# /Users/name/.bash_profile: line 5: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name
# 3.2.57(1)-release

​```{bash, engine.opts = '-l', engine.path='/usr/local/bin/bash'}
echo "$BASH_VERSION"
​```
# 5.1.4(1)-release
````

The inability for the chunk to properly source the `shopt` command from my `.bash_profile` is how I came across this issue.

#### Problem

According to the [`knitr` documentation for setting chunk engine paths](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/language-engines.html) By setting the engine path with `opts_chunk$set`, the expected behavior is for both chunks to output the same Bash version (5.1.4).

Why doesn't `opts_chunk$set(engine.path = list(bash = '/usr/local/bin/bash'))` work for permanently setting the path for the Bash executable for all subsequent chunks?

---

Edit: For now, the only workable solution is to put the path to the preferred `bash` executable in every `bash` chunk like this:

````
```{bash, engine.path='/usr/local/bin/bash'}
````

Comment: Have you tried knitting your document and seeing what happens? Looks like this is a known issue when running interactively: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/8149

Comment: @nniloc Hi, it's not a doc to be knit. It's more of an interactive script for scientific analysis. Thanks for the link though. That does seem to be the same issue.

Comment: Anyone care to comment on why my question is getting downvoted...?